# How to cast a WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Float]] to Array[Array[Float]] in spark (scala)

Tags: arrays, scala, casting, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Im using Spark 2.0.
I have a column of my dataframe containing a `WrappedArray` of WrappedArrays of Float.

An example of a row would be:

```
[[1.0 2.0 2.0][6.0 5.0 2.0][4.0 2.0 3.0]]
```

Im trying to transform this column into an **`Array[Array[Float]]`**.

What I tried so far is  the following:

```
dataframe.select("mycolumn").rdd.map(r => r.asInstanceOf[Array[Array[Float]]])
```

but I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:
 org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to [[F
```

Any idea would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
  val wawa: WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Float]] = null 
  val res: Array[Array[Float]] = wawa.map(inner => inner.array).toArray
```

It compiles for me

Comment: Thanks Sami, your answer led me to the final resolution. I'll update my own answer with the exact code for those like me who started with a dataframe.

Comment: My first question at Stackoverflow got 3 answers none of them worked, but by combing them I found a solution.   :D

Answer (score 3):

Following @sami-badawi 's answer I am posting the answer for those like me who started from a dataframe.

```
dataframe.select("mycolumn").rdd.map
(row => row.get(0).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Float]]].array.map(x=>x.toArray))
```

Comment: I tried to print out the values by below:  

rdd.map(row => row.get(0).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[WrappedArray[String]]].toSeq.map(x=>x.toSeq.foreach(println)))