# Spark error: GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.6 and trying to get and cast a dataframe row value.

here is my problem : 
i have a row in my dataframe who have this kind of structure:

```
WrappedArray([List of String], [List of String])
```

I need tu use [List of String] in the WrappedArray , so i try to cast it with the this code  :

```
 val RDD= DF.map(

    f => {

      if(f.getAs("ListOfRficAction")!=null){
        var listActions = f.getAs("ColumnName").asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[List[List[Any]]]] .map(m=>m:+f.getAs("AssetId").toString)


    })
```

and i have the following error :

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
```

Any idea of how i can cast it ?

Comment: I can't make your code compile. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please provide your build.sbt and imports. Your `map` is strange now. You assign something to `listActions` and don't return anything nor use `listActions`. And if condition is not satisfied you don't return anything either. Even opening and closing brackets don't correspond to each other.

Comment: thaks for answer, i use a maven project not sbt.

Comment: Then pom.xml of the project.

Comment: please see my answers

Comment: Try to cast to `WrappedArray[WrappedArray[String]]`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41904744/how-to-cast-a-wrappedarraywrappedarrayfloat-to-arrayarrayfloat-in-spark